# Error al Instalar Sass en Mac

Tags: css, ionic, ruby, rubygems, sass

Al correr el comando `gem install sass` me muestra este Resultado de la consola, si alguno sabe la solución o una idea de porque esta sucediendo les agradeceria.

```
 Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sass:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180220-47719-16iycjn.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... no
checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi... yes
checking for ffi_call() in -lffi... yes
checking for ffi_prep_closure()... yes
checking for ffi_raw_call()... no
checking for shlwapi.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
checking for ffi_prep_cif_var()... no
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR=" clean
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/make-0.3.1/bin/make:4:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `make' for main:Object (NameError)
    from /usr/local/bin/make:22:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/make:22:in `<main>'

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR="
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/make-0.3.1/bin/make:4:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `make' for main:Object (NameError)
    from /usr/local/bin/make:22:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/make:22:in `<main>'

make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-17/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.21/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es porque necesitas tener instalado `Xcode` en tu mac.

1) `xcode-select --install`

2) `sudo xcodebuild -license`

3) para instalar `sass` no te olvides de hacerlo con `sudo`

`sudo gem install sass`

Comment: ¡Funciona! gracias, aunque es bastante extenso xcode.